# Golang Stop Worker but wait for buffered channel to be empty

Tags: go

I am trying to create a worker who keeps reading from a buffered channel and a stop channel.

Since the select statement selects randomly if both channels are ready the stop channel gets executed. Is there any way to order the selects instead of random so that if my buffered channel returns a value execute that code.

Using un-buffered channel could solve this but is there any way by using buffered channel ?

https://play.golang.org/p/ZuMEkp6sJgv

Comment: The workers should be the ones ranging over the channel (always include the relevant code in the question, not via a link)

Comment: What if I want the channel to be open and a producer is producing into it. First i will stop producting in the channel and close it but I want the worker to finish the task.

Answer (score 4):

The posted code can be simplified to:

```
var channel = make(chan int)
var wg sync.WaitGroup

var limit int = 50000

func main() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go worker()

    for i := 0; i < limit; i++ {
        channel <- i
    }
    close(channel)
    wg.Wait()
}

func worker() {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := range channel {
        log.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the worker to continue working as long as there's more to do even though stop is triggered, then reorganize the select:

```
out:
select {
        case <-channel:
            doWork()
            for {
              select {
                 case <- channel:
                   doWork()
                 default:
                   break out
               }
            }
        case <-stop:
            log.Printf("In Stop %v", len(channel))
            return
        }
}
```

If you close the channel when empty, then all you need to do is range over the channel. Above code will work even if you do not close the channel.

Comment: I think you meant to put the for loop into the stop case.

Comment: @Peter, the way it is written, this will continue processing without looking at the stop channel as long as new messages arrive in channel. Once everything in channel is consumed, it will look at stop channel.